# async task lacks await for MVC IHttpActionResult controller

Tags: c#, asynchronous, model-view-controller

I am using an async task to return Json data that I modeled using a data dictionary. I want the task to execute asynchronously while it does my database calls in from my methods `report.GetActiveBuildDefinitions()` and my object of CurrentState which has a constructor which gets the data i need. This is the constructor I am talking about -> `new CurrentState(BuildDef.ID);` 
This controller functions properly. But when i enable Warnings as Errors. My class does not build. It requires that I use the await keyword for my async task. I tried adding it to the return like `return await Json(state);` but then it gives an error that "does not contain a definition for getawaiter" please help

This is my controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBuildState()
    {
        try
        {
            List<CurrentState> state = new List<CurrentState>();
            BuildReport report = new BuildReport();
            List<BuildDefinition> definitions = report.GetActiveBuildDefinitions();
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> buildInfo = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

            foreach (BuildDefinition BuildDef in definitions)
            {
                state.Add(new CurrentState(BuildDef.ID));
            }

            foreach (CurrentState build in state)
            {
                Dictionary <string, string> entry = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                if (build.ITestExists)
                {
                    if (build.ITestState && build.BuildState)
                    {
                        entry.Add("BuildDef", build.BuildDefName);
                        entry.Add("GraphCode", "1");
                        entry.Add("WorkingBrokenTime", GetTime(build.BuildDefID));
                        entry.Add("Icon", "1");
                        entry.Add("Id", build.BuildDefID.ToString());
                    }
                    else if(build.BuildState && build.ITestState.Equals(false))
                    {
                        entry.Add("BuildDef", build.BuildDefName);
                        entry.Add("GraphCode", "2");
                        entry.Add("WorkingBrokenTime", GetTime(build.BuildDefID));
                        entry.Add("Icon", "0");
                        entry.Add("Id", build.BuildDefID.ToString());
                    }
                    else if (build.BuildState.Equals(false) && build.ITestState)
                    {
                        entry.Add("BuildDef", build.BuildDefName);
                        entry.Add("GraphCode", "3");
                        entry.Add("WorkingBrokenTime", GetTime(build.BuildDefID));
                        entry.Add("Icon", "0");
                        entry.Add("Id", build.BuildDefID.ToString());
                    }
                    else if (build.ITestState.Equals(false) && build.BuildState.Equals(false))
                    {
                        entry.Add("BuildDef", build.BuildDefName);
                        entry.Add("GraphCode", "0");
                        entry.Add("WorkingBrokenTime", GetTime(build.BuildDefID));
                        entry.Add("Icon", "0");
                        entry.Add("Id", build.BuildDefID.ToString());
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    if (build.BuildState)
                    {
                        entry.Add("BuildDef", build.BuildDefName);
                        entry.Add("GraphCode", "4");
                        entry.Add("WorkingBrokenTime", GetTime(build.BuildDefID));
                        entry.Add("Icon", "1");
                        entry.Add("Id", build.BuildDefID.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entry.Add("BuildDef", build.BuildDefName);
                        entry.Add("GraphCode", "5");
                        entry.Add("WorkingBrokenTime", GetTime(build.BuildDefID));
                        entry.Add("Icon", "0");
                        entry.Add("Id", build.BuildDefID.ToString());
                    }
                }
                buildInfo.Add(entry);
            }
            return Json(state);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you might need to read a little about the `async-await` pattern, or find some posts on SO that have already answered questions like this.

Comment: Change it to "public IHttpActionResult GetBuildState()" if you aren't using any awaitable operation.

Comment: When I remove the async...the Json() method falls over and doesn't work. It gives a conversion error. @AjinderSingh

Comment: @ThabaneNdaba - What is the error ?

Comment: @ThabaneNdaba - May be try return Json(state,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<System.Collections.Generic.List<HelperObject.CurrentState>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult>' @AjinderSingh

Comment: @AjinderSingh The JsonRequestBehaviour also throws an exception, Im trying to see whether I can find a solution for it because it is also a conversion error. This is the error ->  cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'

Comment: @ThabaneNdaba - You can't return Json with return type of IHttpActionResult . Try return Ok(state).

Answer (score 1):

> I want the task to execute asynchronously

But why? What benefit do you think asynchrony will get you, here?

Hint: `async` does **not** mean "return early".

Everything currently in your controller action is synchronous, so your controller action should be synchronous, too:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetBuildState()
```

Now, if you change your I/O calls to be naturally asynchronous (i.e., using EF6 asynchronous queries), then your controller action may end up calling an asynchronous method:

```
var definitions = await report.GetActiveBuildDefinitionsAsync();
```

and at that point, the compiler will tell you to make `GetBuildState` asynchronous and change its return type to `Task<IHttpActionResult>`.